# How to use a pattern to spit out an integer backwards

Tags: java

So with my online class, it's asking for me to write a program that prints any 5 digit integer backwards each digit one by one so like:

`14325` would print as

```
5
2
3
4
1
```

The teacher wants us to use integer arithmetic to accomplish this and says that there is a pattern.

I have sat here for the last half hour trying to look for an answer but everyone seems to be doing it without integer arithmetic that I find.

I'm not asking for like a full solution to this problem, just asking for someone to please point me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you atleast post what you have tried so far?

Comment: The last digit is what remains after dividing the number by 10. Repeat the step with the integer (i.e. round down, floor) that number / 10 gives you.

Comment: Probably you get confused with the word *pattern*. I guess he meant: "algorithm", or math-only based computation.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun Hi, using integer % 10 gives me the last digit but then what? Little confused with what you mean by round down, floor. Thank you

Comment: @GaryFishell Integer division (int divided by int) returns an integer. 13/10==1. If you apply this to my earlier comment you note that you get the first part 'give me the last digit' by using the % operator, the second part 'give me all digits except the last one') are provided by a simple division by ten.

Answer (score 4):

Print the last digit (modulo 10), and then divide by 10. Repeat this until the original number becomes 0.

```
int number = 14325;

while(number > 0) {
    System.out.println(number % 10);
    number /= 10;
}
```

Comment: I would consider this over-helping. You can do this student a favour by helping him find out how to solve the assignment. You are doing no favour by solving it for him. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Can’t use while loops? Is there some other loop you can use? Maybe you can rewrite the loop yourself? @GaryFishell (funny restriction, that one)

Comment: If you know the integer is always 5 digits, it is possible without a loop. Leaving that to you, @GaryFishell. Now you have beeen given the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.toCharArray`

```
    String number = 12345 + "";
    char[] chars = number.toCharArray();
    for(int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        System.out.println(chars[i]);
    }
```

Comment: While it gives the expected output, it doesn’t seem in the spirit of “The teacher wants us to use integer arithmetic to accomplish this”.

Comment: Sorry, cant use for or anything similar, only integer arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

If you know the integer is always 5 digits, it is possible without a loop.

```
    if (number < 10000 || number > 99999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requiring five digits, got " + number);
    }
    System.out.println(number % 10);
    System.out.println(number / 10 % 10);
    System.out.println(number / 100 % 10);
    System.out.println(number / 1000 % 10);
    System.out.println(number / 10000 % 10);
```

If `number` is `14325`, this prints:

```
5
2
3
4
1
```

Attempting just a bit of mind-reading here (certainly not my home field), the ‘pattern’ your teacher talked about could be this that the number to divide by (the divisor) gets an extra 0 for each digit (you might even write the first line as `System.out.println(number / 1 % 10);` if you wanted it to fit into the pattern, but really…). So no design pattern or regexp pattern, as some could have construed that word.

The `% 10` in the last statement is superfluous. I’m leaving it there for the sake of the pattern.